# My Tailwind CSS-styled navbar will not scroll horizontally, it only scrolls a tiny bit vertically

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

My navbar will not scroll horizontally, it only scrolls a tiny bit vertically. I'm using the tailwind-scrollbar-hide plugin and added it to my config file.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6EJm.jpg)

```
    import requests from "../utils/requests";
    
    function Nav() {
      return (
      <nav className="relative">
        <div className="flex px-10 sm:px-20 text-2xl whitespace-nowrap
         space-x-10 sm:space-x-20 overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-hidden scrollbar-hide">
            {Object.entries(requests).map(([key, { title, url }]) => (
              <h2 
              key={key} 
              className="last:pr-24 cursor-pointer transition duration-100 transform hover:scale-125 hover:text-white
              active:text-red-500 "
              >
                {title}
              </h2>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="absolute top-0 right-0 bg-gradient-to-l from-[#06202A] h-10 w-1/12" />
      </nav>
      );
    }
    
    export default Nav;
```

Comment: Was the screenshot taken when including `scrollbar-hide`? If you want to ensure the overflow is being added correctly, you could try adding `h-full` to both your `<nav>` element and the child `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've provided scrolls horizontally.
Here is the working code with minimal modifications and tailwind-scrollbar-hide plugin installed (see in config tab): https://play.tailwindcss.com/gCJb6kO4yP?file=config

Please note, you can't scroll horizontally just by scrolling the mouse wheel. You have to hold "shift" key while scrolling. This is a default behaviour (see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_hor_scroll).